# For office365 DNS entries, which one should I use as DNS controller between windows server vs Registrar

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, server, dns

all
I have some trouble to get access from web-based office 365 portals.
When I click any portal except outlook under IE and Firefox(Chrome works fine)
The url keep redirecting and not getting any authorisation.
From what I saw from Chrome development tool network tap, accessing procedure was like getting default.aspx and then authorisation then finally get sharepoint.aspx.

However, I get below on IE 11 and then says as working with blank page.

### And same situdation under Firefox.

URL Protocol Method Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎ Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎

### /01db4c00-52ae-4bea-878b-ca6011d3195b/oauth2/authorize?client_id=00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid&nonce=8A00A8A550646CD9D40114D2F06DA8890DC231BD4956F58F-1BFD836E494F805CD760C6174DB810E59C6F664B05007D9037C290FA9DDAA629&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Fharbic.sharepoint.com%2F_forms%2Fdefault.aspx&state=0&client-request-id=3f7fee9d-104a-4000-f6b1-d802817e7abd  (Pending...)    POST    (Pending...)    (Pending...)    0 B (Pending...)    click   717 0   0   0   0   0

So I checked up DNS server from office365 admin console.
And it looked like the picture in the link.
[DNS check up from office 365](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TctN1.png)

For general environment in our office, the main dc is in a virtual machine and windows server 2003. IE version in there is 7. 
Accessing through IE and Firefox is fine externally but not locally.

Can anyone give me some hint to fix this trouble?

Thanks

Comment: MS use a validation service at live.com (account.live.com). IE has a security restriction preventing navigation into a zone of lower integrity, so if you place *.outlook.com or *.Microsoft.com in the IE Trusted sites list IE won't be able to navigate to account.live.com.... you see the browser go into some sort of loop...

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default"... then Select the Trusted sites icon, click the 'Sites' button and remove ALL publicly accessible domains... the same problem exists for google (verifies credentials at account.google.com) and facebook and others. Generally only large companies have a need to use the Trusted sites list when they want to access the internal networks (intranets) of their business partners sites, and they know and trust that that company may be using unsigned content and plugins.

Comment: ... you should not use server versions of windows to run a web browser to surf the web.... IE running on server versions runs in an enhanced protected mode..... only sites in the Trusted zone are allowed to downloads.... To allow your server version of IE to download files from only Microsoft domains you should add *.live.com to the server version of IE's Trusted sites list... (a locked-down 2003 server usually has only *.Microsoft.com pre-listed in the IE Trusted sites list.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. From what I have seen, url for signing in office365 was https://login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: Yes, that may be the URL of the login page, but credential verification uses a separate uri... IE has a security setting preventing navigation into an IE security zone of lower integrity.... test by removing ALL domains from your IE Trusted sites list (https works in any IE security zone, you should however use the https protocol in your favorite and desktop links). then https://microsoftonline.com....

Comment: let me know how it turns out... I'm 100% sure that's why you see the login credential validation looping... some of the domains involved are not in the same IE security zone.